# Create a new column with specific values for range of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I would like to create a new column called "label" and establish a value for specific range of rows and other value for remain rows.

Example. My initial dataframe is just one column called tweet, and I want to create a new one called label and stablish the value "train" for the first three rows and "val" for the rest rows

```
tweet   |   label
--------|---------
"abcs"  |  "train"
"rts"   |  "train"
"holt"  |  "train"
"ejw"   |   "val"
"kks"   |   "val"
"jsj"   |   "val"
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for the example you gave. You can adjust according to your need. 'df' refers to the dataframe you have before adding the new column.

```
df['label'] = 'val'
df.loc[0:3,'label'] = 'train'
```